# Can the D800 built-in flash be used to trigger slave flashes only?

Tags: nikon, flash, popup-flash, wireless-flash

Without itself emitting light during the exposure?

Comment: Related: [Why is there a preflash from a built-in flash when using remote flash only?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/6618/1943)

Comment: Which, by the way, strongly implies the answer is _yes_, since it's typical of Nikon cameras (and others), but I don't know the specifics of that model.

Answer (score 3):

The D800 doesn't have a radio trigger, so yes, it emits light when talking to other flashes -- whether with a dumb optically-triggered slave or with the CLS (Creative Lighting System). The light emitted is minimal, but it's there.

Comment: But, it has a "commander" mode where the emitted light is minimal and intended of communication only, not to contribute to the exposure, right?

Comment: I think (perhaps mistakingly) that the pre-flashes used for TTL metering happen before the shutter curtain opens. I guess this is basicaly the question

Comment: Yes, the light emitted during preflash is minimal, but it's certainly there: try shooting a highly reflective surface at 1/250 sec/small aperture and you'll have no trouble capturing the preflash emitted in commander mode.

Comment: The command pulse is actually distinct from the preflash; that's what you are capturing in that case. The preflash _does_ happen before the shutter opens, but the control flash can't. But the important thing here is that the commander mode uses a diminished pulse for the control, and while it will show up in reflections, it's _intended_ to be minimal and not contribute to the exposure, as opposed to "master" mode, where the pop-up flash also fires intentionally to light the subject.

Comment: If distance (or complicated reflection paths) is not an issue, there is the [SG-3IR](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Flash-Couplers/4905/SG-31R-IR-Panel-for-Built-In-Flash.html) infrared filter for the pop-up. It's intended use is with the R1 twin-tube macro flash, but it will work with the whole CLS, making the pop-up into a sort of reduced-power SU-800 unit on- or near-axis (with some white light spill, of course).

Comment: @StanRogers — I made a much smaller stick-on device with [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16379/would-this-ir-transparent-plastic-be-useful-for-blocking-unwanted-control-flash) — hmmm, I should update the answer to that question with my eventual solution....