# Pentax K-30 + Metz 52 AF 1 as off-camera slave

Tags: off-camera-flash, pentax, ttl, wireless-flash, metz

I recently bought external flash Metz 52 AF 1 and I have Pentax K-30 camera.

Wireless mode works fine, however i expected it will be possible to use ONLY Metz flash without built-in pentax flash - but that does not work.

I found "Flash in wireless mode" setting in Pentax configuration menu and even if built-in flash is set to "Fires as controller in wireless mode" I can still see it on the picture ! I would expect that controller flash is not visible at all...

Do I miss something in configuration ? I need only one light source and that should be off-camera Metz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with Pentax's wireless flash system. Or rather, it's a common problem with all such systems. (See [similar complaint with Nikon](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/why-is-there-a-preflash-from-a-built-in-flash-when-using-remote-flash-only).) Even though the manual states otherwise, at least portion of the control flash fires during the actual exposure, and you can see it in the image, particularly if there are reflective surfaces or if your subject is close. It was less of a problem on earlier Pentax cameras like the K10D, but then people complained about range and reliability. Newer cameras solve those problems, but the trade-off is, apparently, a more visible control flash.

There is a solution, though. I bought a cheap piece of IR-transparent plastic and stick that over the built-in flash. Unfortunately the flash won't close with it on, which is a bit annoying, but it's very light so a bit of transparent double-sticky tape is sufficient. More details on this here: [Would this IR-transparent plastic be useful for blocking unwanted control flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16379/would-this-ir-transparent-plastic-be-useful-for-blocking-unwanted-control-flash). If DIY seems a bit much, there *are* products sold for this purpose, but I actually like my hack better, since it goes in a tiny SD-card pocket of my camera bag — and it doesn't look ridiculous in use.